# Python 3: Assign with Exec

Tags: python, python-3.x

First of all, yes I know what I'm doing is bad.  It's part of a hacky project that I'm trying for fun.

In Python 2.7, you could do this:

```
def myfunc():
    exec('a=3')
    print('Result: a = {}'.format(a))

myfunc()
```

And get `Result: a = 3`

Not so in Python 3.6, where you'll get `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`.

I can try to work around this by doing:

```
def myfunc():
    exec('globals()["a"]=3')
    print('Result: a = {}'.format(a))

myfunc()
```

Which in Python 3.6 gives the desired `Result: a = 3` (and yes, has dangerous consequences by modifying globals).  But of course it fails in the following case:

```
def myfunc():
    a=2
    exec('globals()["a"]=3')
    print('Result: a = {}'.format(a))

myfunc()
```

Where I get `Result: a = 2`.  Swapping in `exec('a=3')` here will also give `Result: a = 2`.

**Question: Is there any hack in Python 3 that effectively allows me to assign to a variable in a function body?**

Comment: No. There isn't a good or easy way. But the good news is you don't need to.

Comment: `exec('globals()["a"]=3')` is just crazy. You should just do `globals()['a'] = 3`. Anyway, just pass a custom namespace, e.g. some `dict` as locals then extract the variable using the dict. That *will* work.

Answer (score -1):

```
def myfunc():
    exec('a=3', locals(), globals())
    print('Result: a = {}'.format(a))


myfunc()
```

Comment: Hmm, ok that works in the first case, but in the second case (when I put `a=2` first) the result is still `Result: a = 2`.  It looks like this is just functionally equivalent to `exec('globals()["a"]=3')`